# symfony 4.3 Automatic validation doesn't work

Tags: symfony-4.3

I have read about new feature:
**symfony 4.3** Automatic validation 
https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-automatic-validation
So Doctrine annotation should suffice without
explicitly manually adding Validator annotations
( like `@Assert\NotNull()` ..)
Yet I do not understand how to make it work.
I have symfony 4.3 application, currently create Entities,
really do not want to add Validator annotations manually
but use this new Automatic validation feature.
I am newby to Symfony, 
please be detailed.

```
//$post is Entity with title notNull property
$errors = $validator->validate($post);

/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
     */
```

It should work without explicitly adding 
`@Assert\NotNull()` but it doesn't

Answer (score 3):

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/assert-validation

The answer is in https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/assert-validation
see Conversation.
Briefly
config/packages/validator.yaml like:

framework:
    validation:
        email_validation_mode: html5

```
    # Enables validator auto-mapping support.
    # For instance, basic validation constraints will be inferred from Doctrine's metadata.
```

## HERE! uncomment 2 line below and Automatic validation should work

```
    auto_mapping:
        App\Entity\: []
```